# How do I place ESP32CAM video stream inside PHP website?

Tags: php, mysql, database, esp32

I am trying to create a website that will display video from ESP32CAM watching over a parking lot. Basically I want to make a table with buttons that goes over video stream that I get from ESP32. Currently I get an IP address for ESP32 that shows me the stream when I open it but is it somehow possible to put it into PHP website that I have? I am supposed to change status if a parking space is occupied or not by pressing the button and change it into database.

Comment: Use an iframe to display the stream ...?

Comment: When I try iframe I get message  Not Found: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Then you either did something wrong, or the camera actively prevents this.